# REST - Media-Type for an array of homogeneous items

Tags: rest

```
GET /orders

[ { "desc": "Champagne" }, { "desc": "Strawberries" } ]
```

If a resource is a simple array of orders, should my media-type be

`application/orders-collection+json`

Or do we assume the containing array is implied by `+json` and its what's in the array that needs communicating, i.e.

`application/order+json`

?

Note that if I broke the format of an order then I'd only need to version one media-type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Collection+Json](http://amundsen.com/media-types/collection/) supports [profiles](http://amundsen.com/media-types/collection/format/) which can be used to specify the media type of its elements further. A media type like

```
application/vnd.collection+json;profile=http://example.org/profiles/order http://schema.org/Order
```

might be more appropriate IMO.

AFAIK collection+json do not support pagination (I hope I'm wrong though), therefore, if you need or want a paginated view with links pointing to the `next`, `previous`, `first` or `last` page of a paginated collection, extending from this media type and specifying a `application/vnd.paginated-collection+json` might be benefitial.