# Is it technically RESTful to have two identifiers after each other not separated by an id (ie /location/addresses)

Tags: rest, api

I was wondering if it is technically RESTful to use an identifier as a grouping and not be a particular resource (no corresponding id).

For example:

```
get /location/address
get /location/coverage
get /location/region
```

These things are all a location hence having them behind the location identifier. Is this correct?

Or is it better to rethink the structure of these endpoints or break them into just /address - /coverage - /region?

Comment: In this case `get /location` would return an error since there is no such resource? What would be the benefit of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, a URI in a REST architecture is just a URI, a reference to an other resource. The actual spelling used inside the URI is furthermore not of relevance as the URI as a whole is a pointer that shouldn't get segmented or analyzed. While a set of URIs may span a whole tree of available paths to use, there is no requirement actually therefore.

An URI itself also does not necessarily tell anything about the content of the resource it points to. Fielding even claimed that

> A REST API should never have “typed” resources that are significant to the client. Specification authors may use resource types for describing server implementation behind the interface, but those types must be irrelevant and invisible to the client. The only types that are significant to a client are the current representation’s media type and standardized relation names. ([Source](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven))

This [blog post](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) further describes what Fielding meant with this statement which basically just states that proper content type negotiation should be used instead of assuming that a resource has a certain type. On the Web you might retrieve a data page of your preferred car or sports team though you will most-likely receive a page in HTML format that is generic enough and therefore widely spread that plenty of clients (browsers) support it. Through the affordance of each of the defined elements your client (browser) knows how to present these to you for more convenient access of the content.

I'm not sure about you but if I have the choice between reading some line summarizing the content of a link and having to decipher the URI itself, I definitely prefer the former one. Such metadata is usually attached to a link in some way. In HTML the [anchor (`<a>`) tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/textlevel-semantics.html#elementdef-a) not only ships with meta data such as `href` or `target` but also `rel` which basically allows to annotate a URI with a set of keywords that tell a client about the purpose of the link. Such a keywords may be something like `first`, `last`, `prev` or `next` for paging through a sub-set of a collection, or `preload` for telling a client that it can load the content of the referenced URI early to speed up load times as the client will most likely be interested in the content of that link next. Such keywords should be [standardized](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) to gain wider acceptance or at least base off of [an extension mechanism defined in Web Linking](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8288#section-2.1.2), as [Dublin Core](https://www.dublincore.org/specifications/dublin-core/dc-html/) does it i.e.

Looking at your respective URIs they already seem to express what link relation are there for. As such they could make up for good candidates for defining them as link relations such as:

```
http://www.acme.com/rel/address
http://www.acme.com/rel/coverage
http://www.acme.com/rel/region
```

A link can basically have multiple relation names assigned simultaneously, depending on the media-type the payload is exchanged for. A client that does not know what a certain link-relation means will simply ignore it, clients that however have the knowledge will act accordingly upon finding URIs with such annotations. I admit that an arbitrary client will not be able to make use of all of the link-relations out of the box, especially the extension ones, but such link-relation names might be enforced by media-types as well or support for such relation names may be added through updates or plug-ins later on.

Media types, after all, are just a human-readable description on how a payload received for such a form will look like and how it has to be processed by some automata. Hence, a generic `application/json` is usually a bad media-type in a REST API as it just defines that the content should be embedded between curly braces and primarily represents a key-value structure with the addition of objects and arrays, but it lacks to hint a client on what a link is or on the semantics of certain elements found within the payload. [application/hal+json](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) is an extension of the basic JSON notation and adds some processing rules and semantic definitions of certain elements such as `_links` or `_embedded`, which a client can use. Here, curies could be used a link-relations as well I guess as in the end they also end up with unique URIs as requested by the Web linking extension definition.

Certain media-types also allow to pass along further processing hints in the media-type itself through the use of profiles. As such a server could hint a client i.e. that the collection expressed by the requested resource contains entries that follow a certain logic, i.e. that [the collection contains a set of orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52002719/rest-media-type-for-an-array-of-homogeneous-items), where a processing entity can apply additional checks upon, i.e. that certain fields must be specified or that certain inputs have to be in bound between two values and stuff.

As writing a whole new media-type is quite some effort, investigating [into already defined ones](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) is for sure a good idea. If you really think there is no media type available yet that really is applicable to your domain, you should start to write one, probably in a community effort. Keep in mind though that this media-type should be as generic as possible to allow adoption by third parties otherwise hardly any client will really support it and thus limit the number of potential peers your applications can interact with. It is further a good idea to take reference at the HTML spec to see how elements got defined and how they maintained backwards compatibility as you don't want to register a new media-type on each change.

If you just want to implement some filter mechanism to only show locations that represent addresses rather than regions you may take reference on how it is done on the Web. Here usually a server will provide you a form to select a choice among the given set of choices and upon clicking the submit button (or enter key) a request is issued to the server which will return the subset of entries matching the query. Instead of using a form a server may already provide a client with a link that is annotated, as mentioned above, with some hints a client knows that they refer to addresses, regions or whatever options you have available and can chose based on the annotated link relations the URI which is of interest to the client. Again, the actual form of the URI is not of relevance here either as a client should just use the URIs that were provided by the server.

You might ask yourself why all that is needed?! The basic answer to this question is simply to avoid breaking things when stuff changes over time. Think of a case where a client wants to retrieve details on a previously sent order. If it had the knowledge of the URI hardcoded into it and the server changes the URI style the client might not be able to retrieve this data. On the other side if it had the knowledge to look for any URI annotated with `http://www.acme/rel/order` and just use that URI it couldn't care less if the URI changed as it just uses the given information to send it to the mentioned endpoint. By relying on well-defined media-types and the semantics of the defined elements, any peer supporting this media-type will also be able to process it. Almost every client is able to handle HTML in some way, though hardly any generic HTTP client can really act upon a custom JSON payload format, i.e. present you a clickable link or render a nice form you can update the data of an existing resource. Custom payload makes it also difficult to reuse the same client for different endpoints. I.e. you probably wont be able to use the same client to shop on two different web-shops that expose Web-RPC-based HTTP endpoints.

So, to sum up my post, as mentioned, the form of the URI is not really of relevance in a REST architecture as a server should always provide it to the client anyway and a client shouldn't deduct the meaning from it. Instead link-relations, media-type support and content-type negotiation should be used consistently.

Answer (score 0):

[REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) doesn't care what spellings you use for your URI, beyond the fact that they should be consistent with the production rules defined in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A).

```
GET /location/region
GET /region
```

Those are both *fine*.